# create while loop with purrr to simulate data

Tags: r, purrr

I am running simulations, and have in the past used while loops to run my simulation, but I'm currently teaching myself purrr and really like being able to store the simulated data, parameters used for simulation, and outcomes in the same data frame.

My problem is that I would like to repeat a random sampling until a criterion is reached, which as I have currently implemented means that I would have to add rows to my dataframe.

Here is the code I currently have:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
simulation_df =  crossing(sim_mean = 1, 
                          sim_sd = 2, 
                          final_sample_size =20, 
                          sim =1:10, 
                          collected_data = c(6,14)) %>%
  mutate(phase = if_else(collected_data == 6, 
                         "pilot", 
                         "full sample"),
    data =pmap(list(collected_data, # input to rnorm
                    sim_mean, 
                    sim_sd), 
               rnorm)) %>% # function to apply
  group_by(sim) %>% 
  # check if pilot was successful (ie 4 or more data points > 0)
 mutate( pilot_result = if_else(phase =="pilot",
                                map_dbl(data, ~ sum(. > 0)),
                                0 ),
         success_pilot = pilot_result >= 4) %>%
  ungroup()

(simulation_df %>% select(sim,phase, data, success_pilot) %>% head())
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>     sim phase       data       success_pilot
#>   <int> <chr>       <list>     <lgl>        
#> 1     1 pilot       <dbl [6]>  FALSE        
#> 2     1 full sample <dbl [14]> FALSE        
#> 3     2 pilot       <dbl [6]>  TRUE         
#> 4     2 full sample <dbl [14]> FALSE        
#> 5     3 pilot       <dbl [6]>  TRUE         
#> 6     3 full sample <dbl [14]> FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

If `success_pilot == FALSE`, I would like to repeat sampling 6 data points until `success_pilot == TRUE`. I could implement this in a roundabout way by deciding on a maximum # of times I would sample 6 data points and then filter out all datapoints after the first `success_pilot == TRUE`.

In the Iteration chapter in [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html), while loops are mentioned but not covered - I was wondering whether there is a tidy solution for this?

Comment: Maybe see https://community.rstudio.com/t/what-is-the-tidyverse-way-of-doing-a-conditional-while-or-for-loop/20295